# Android view animation tweens choppy / jerky

Tags: android, xml, animation, view

I'm making a fairly basic main menu screen for my app and I have two of my buttons sliding in from the left and a imageview to pop up behind them by raising the alpha.  So far I've accomplished this fine, but all of the animations are very jerky/choppy and no tweaks I use seem to be able to fix it.

The strange thing is that the animations are buttery smooth perfect on my 10" tablet, but on my newer phones the animations are jerky.  I am using the exact same images for all devices (in the drawable folder, there are no special high resolution versions yet)  All images for the sliding buttons and the imageview are less than 100k in size PNGs, all have transparencies.

**Basically, I'm trying to find out how to smooth these animations and why they would be silky-smooth on my older tablet but jerky on newer phones.**  My tablet where it works perfectly is a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1" and my phones where the animation is jerky are a Google Nexus 4 and a Nexus 5.

Animation XML 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" 
 android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
 android:duration="700"
 android:repeatCount="0"/>
</set>
```

And the second animation XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"  android:duration="1000"  />
</set>
```

The XML template of the main menu:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/menuimage1med"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_mask"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/menumask1" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

     <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/menuButton3"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/menuButton1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/extrasbutton" />


     <Button
        android:id="@+id/menuButton1"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/menuButton2"
        android:background="@drawable/continuebutton" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/menuButton2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/newstory" /> 
    </RelativeLayout>

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/musicButton"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:background="@drawable/musicicon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my code:

```
    //Main Menu view animations  
    ImageView imageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menu_mask);
    Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
    imageView.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation); 

    Button menuButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menuButton1);
    Button menuButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menuButton3);

    Animation flyInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fly_in);
    menuButton1.startAnimation(flyInAnimation);
    menuButton3.startAnimation(flyInAnimation);
```

This code is NOT in the onCreate method because I know that can cause potential issues.

**EDIT:  I checked Logcat, and when returning to the main menu and playing the animations, it says 'Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.'  I didn't think a light animation sliding a button in would be burdensome?  And if that's the case, it still doesn't make sense why it would work on an inferior tablet smoothly.**

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

My guess has something to do with the higher-end phones' os version not set to use hardware acceleration by default. Add this to your manifest:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

in the activity where you're trying to do animation.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I added this line to the manifest for the appropriate activity and unfortunately noticed no change in performance.

Comment: @josephus, as regomar noticed there's no difference. The cause is that (as you can see at [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html)) `android:hardwareAccelerated` attribute is true for default if you've set either `minSdkVersion` or `targetSdkVersion` to "14" or higher.